# Output values to excel in sas

Tags: sas

Can some one please help me to output the data generated from the following code(yt) to an excel data set?

proc iml;

d = 0.4;

call farmasim(yt, d) n=10 sigma=2 seed=123457;

print yt;

run;

Comment: What have you tried? If you really just have 10 observations, how about copying and pasting it into Excel? Otherwise, tell us what steps you've taken to figure this out and we'll help you.

Comment: @Itzy how do you copy and paste from SAS to excel?  Do you need EG to do that?

Comment: I meant copy and paste the screen output. Not a great solution, but this question shows zero effort; I'm quite surprised it was voted up.

Answer (score 1):

```
ods tagsets.excelxp file="myfile.xml";
proc iml ... etc. ... quit;
ods tagsets.excelxp close;
```

For more info google "tagsets.excelxp" or see http://support.sas.com/rnd/base/ods/odsmarkup/excelxp_demo.html

Alternately, you can move yt into a dataset, and use PROC EXPORT, either to EXCEL if you have ACCESS to PC FILES licensed, or to CSV if not.

Comment: A few more options in addition to those Joe listed... You could also use DDE, or even just right-click on the dataset and choose `View in Excel`.